# "GENERIC constants" in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

is it possible to have different constants depending on the GENERIC input? E.g.:

```
entity smth is
   generic(
      constant_width : integer := 32
   );
end smth;

architecture Behavioral of smth is
   if(constant_width = 32) then
        constant ROM_tan : rom_type := ( .....
           ....
       );
   else
        constant ROM_tan : rom_type := ( ....
       );
   );

begin
.
.
```

One workaround is to create two constants and let Vivado trim one away(using generate and if) if it's not used, but that doesn't look elegant. The other one is to concatenate two constants, since in my case the difference between constants is only the size, i.e precision, of the constants depending on the input width, but that’s not very elegant for me either. Is there any other way? (Maybe something with package?)

Kind Regards,

Den

Comment: Yes. One way is a single declaration that initialises `ROM_tan` with a function call. The function uses the generic... In the body (not declarations),  use `If ... Generate`.

Comment: That is known to me, but it's not easy to generate these constants with a function, it's way easier for me to generate them in MATLAB and just paste it into VHDL. To write all the MATLAB code in VHDL would be a bit too much. (it's not a ROM of tangents, it was just an example :) ) Regardless, Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `generate` statement has a declarative region, like an architecture.

```
label : if (condition) generate
  constant myConst ....
begin
  -- ...
end generate;
```

You can even declare new types in this region. This is also true for `block` statements.

So rewriting your example gives:

```
entity smth is
  generic(
    constant_width : integer := 32
   );
end smth;

architecture Behavioral of smth is

begin
  gen1 : if (constant_width = 32) generate
    type ROM_type is ...
    constant ROM_tan : ROM_type := (..);
  begin
    -- ...
  end generate;
  gen2 : if (constant_width /= 32) generate
    type ROM_type is ...
    constant ROM_tan : ROM_type := (..);
  begin
    -- ...
  end generate;
end architecture;
```

Comment: And in VHDL-2008 you can even do `gen : if (constant_width = 32) generate ... begin ... else generate ... begin ... end generate`, thereby covering both `constant_width = 32` and the alternative without an explicit `constant_width /= 32`.

Comment: So basically, after begin goes my whole VHDL code in this architecture?

Comment: Tested, works awesome! Thanks, Paebbels. I've used for/if generate a dozen of times, but I didn't know that you can basically put the whole code into it. This way it's so easy to create more generic design without the use of functions!

Answer (score 3):

<strike>All the hand waving is driving me nuts.  There are no language constructs comprised of consecutive '.' characters.</strike>

You can use generics in the type declaration and the function to fill your ROM:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity smth is
   generic (
      constant_width : integer := 32
   );
end entity smth;

architecture foo of smth is
    type rom_type is array (0 to 129) of 
                    signed (constant_width - 1 downto 0);
    function fill_rom return rom_type is  -- if we're going to get all hand wavy
        variable ret_val:   rom_type;
    begin
        for i in rom_type'range loop
            ret_val(i) := to_signed(i,constant_width); -- all look like 45 from here
        end loop;
        return ret_val;
    end function;
    constant ROM_tan:  rom_type := fill_rom;  -- to constant_width accuracy
begin
-- imagine a boat load of lines with three or more periods here.
end architecture;
```

This <strike>example</strike> actually analyzes, elaborates and simulates (while literally not doing anything).

You can also move the generic backward (to a package) potentially the function as well.  If synthesis ever catches up you could use package instantiation (-2008) with it's own generic map aspect.